# Use params of loadNetzkeComponent in configuration

Tags: javascript, ruby, netzke

Is it possible to pass extra parameters to "loadNetzkeComponent" and use them in the compnent configuration?

Example:

JavaScript:

```js
this.loadNetzkeComponent({name: 'Erp::OrderPanel', container: 'workspace', params: { orderId: 1 }, scope: this });
```

Ruby:

```ruby
class Erp::OrderPanel < Netzke::Base
  # ...
  def configuration(params)
    super.merge(
      scope: { order_id: params[:order_id] }
    )
  end
  # ...
end
```

I know, there is no `param` attribute for the `configuration` method, but is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use session (or component_session) store to pass parameters to configuration.

```
session[:order_id] = params[:order_id]
```

Then in configuration:

```
def configuration(params)
    super.merge(
      scope: { order_id: session[:order_id] }
    )
  end
```

Comment: This would work. I'll just add the following: you'll probably need to set that session param in a separate endpoint on the parent, and then call it just before `loadNetzkeComponent` (Ext.Direct will multiplex two consequent endpoint calls into one).

Answer (score 1):

1) Because it's not safe to pass config params directly from JavaScript, one way to do it is to override the deliver_component endpoint in the parent component (the one calling loadNetzkeComponent), where you could do eventual security checks of the passed parameters, and then override the component configuration. An example of this can be found in the test app for netzke-core: https://github.com/nomadcoder/netzke-core/blob/master/test/core_test_app/app/components/component_loader.rb#L98

2) The method suggested by Dmytro would probably require an extra endpoint call on the parent just *before* loading the child component. In that endpoint you would store the require param in the session - this way you'll make sure that param is remembered *every time* the loaded child component communicates to the server. The first method doesn't provide that, because the passed parameter is only used once - at the moment of loading the component - and then "forgotten".

Depending on your requirements, pick one of the two.

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for your reply. I don't like to use the session for storing such data, so I would like to find another way to implement this. Do you have any idea how I can get these params in the `initComponent` method so I can use the proxy of the grid store? Or do I have to make a separate method (i.e. `initData`) which is called by the callback of `loadNetzkeComponent`?

Comment: Paul, then the 1st method is for you. Whatever extra params you pass to component[:your_child_component], they will be accessible on `this` in `initComponent` of `your_child_component`.